# File transfer from opencv to tesseract api

Tags: opencv, tesseract

Now when I pass the processed-image to tesseractOCR to recognize, I will first save it in a tif file format and then read it to the tesseractOCR engine. I find the process is too time-consuming and odd, is there any ways to directly pass the mat file to tesseract engine to recognize without saving and loading? Thanks in advance.

```
Mat imagefromOpenCV= new Mat();
Tesseract1 instance = new Tesseract1();
String filename = "C:\\image.tif";
Imgcodecs.imwrite(filename, imagefromOpenCV);     
File imageFile = new File(filename);        // do reading 
String OCR_str  = instance.doOCR(imageFile);          // performing OCR
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the API from http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/docs/docs-0.4/net/sourceforge/tess4j/Tesseract1.html, it seems you can either use `doOCR(java.awt.image.BufferedImage bi)` or `doOCR(int xsize, int ysize, java.nio.ByteBuffer buf, java.awt.Rectangle rect, int bpp)` to achieve your goal. For example, you could use the code from http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/752511/How-to-Convert-Mat-to-BufferedImage-Vice-Versa to convert your Mat input to BufferedImage, and call `doOCR` on the BufferedImage.

Comment: I have tried, but it doesn't work in my case. Could you suggest another way?